# R web scraping with Rselenium and rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest, rselenium

I need to scrap this [webpage](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&Domain=TARIC&Offset=0&ShowMatchingGoods=false&callbackuri=CBU-1&SimDate=20220719) so I could have a data.frame like this:

```
value01     value02                                             id
SECTION I   LIVE ANIMALS     ANIMAL PRODUCTS                    sectionI
CHAPTER 1   LIVE ANIMALS                                        chap0100000000
0101        Live horses, asses, mules and hinnies :   (TN701)   0101000000-1
            - Horses :                                          0101210000-2
0101 21     -  - Pure-bred breeding animals  (NC018)            0101210000-80
0101 29     -  - Other :                                        0101290000-3
0101 29 10  -  -  - For slaughter                               0101291000-80
0101 29 90  -  -  - Other                                       0101299000-80
0101 30     - Asses                                             0101300000-80
```

To obtain the first two rows of value01 and value02 I use:

```
unlist((remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%  read_html(encoding = 'UTF-8') %>% html_elements('.section') %>% html_table())[2])
unlist((remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%  read_html(encoding = 'UTF-8') %>% html_elements('.chapter') %>% html_table())[2])
```

To obtain the rest of values of value01 and value02 I use (I need to clean the obtained values after I got them with this code, but I think there is better way to obtain the data):

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% read_html() %>% html_element(xpath = '//*[@id="div_description"]') %>% html_table()
```

So my problem now is to get the id column of the data.frame I want and to put it all together. Any advice on how to proceed from here to achieve my goal?

---

The code you need to run to function the previous examples:

```
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(RSelenium)))
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(rvest)))
rD <- rsDriver(browser = 'firefox', port = 6000L, verbose = FALSE)
remDr <- rD[['client']]
remDr$navigate('https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&Domain=TARIC&Offset=0&ShowMatchingGoods=false&callbackuri=CBU-1&SimDate=20220719')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear to me what you want to scrape exactly from that page, but this is how you can get the data I think you are after.

```
pg <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
doc <- xml2::read_html(pg)
# first two lines
rvest::html_elements(doc, '#sectionI table , .chapter') |> 
  rvest::html_table()
# get the data from each further line
lines <- rvest::html_elements(doc, ".evenLine")
data <- rvest::html_table(lines)
ids <- rvest::html_attrs(lines) |> sapply(function(x) x[1])
```

You'll need to clean the scraped data to your liking.

If this is not what you are looking for, you should clarify your question further.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has helped me get what I need. And yes, maybe I should have explained myself better...